# Button Handler Not Working When Not Running PageLoad

Tags: asp.net, events

I have been trying to work around this problem for like two hours and I still have no idea what is going on. Basically here is my scenario:

There is only one possible postback you can do from my website, and that postback is from a button that redirects to another page. Thus I figured it would be more optimized to not run the `PageLoad` event when the button was clicked, considering that it was just going to redirect anyway.

The problem is that when I don't run the `PageLoad` event the button event does not trigger. I am adding the button to my page at runtime using the following code:

```
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);
        adminPanel.Controls.Add(lb);
```

I tried running only the above part from the `PageLoad` event just in case the button needed to be re-created, but it still doesn't work.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Edit: I forgot to add, here is what the button does:

```
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("~/");
```

Comment: Does the button click performs additional server side processing or simple redirects to a known URL of the page?

Comment: You said you have only the above code in the PageLoad event - so you do keep the event and the code that recreates the button - what else did u remove when it stopped working?

Comment: No I have more code in the PageLoad, but it is simply code that adds javascript or some other things into the page. I don't think this would effect the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another solution would be to do it with javascript, onclick redirects on logout.aspx there you can use your code for sign out in the pageload:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Redirect("~/");
```

but even though it won't be more optimized.. it does the same just on another way.

Comment: +1 I think this is the best approach, **specially** if you are so concerned about optimization, as the OP is saying. A simple anchor (not a server-side control that's added programmatically) redirecting to the login page should be all that you need to do.

Comment: Thanks I decided to use this approach; now I don't have to worry about postbacks at all.